# robotframework appium - WebDriverException: Message: platform name is missing in the capabilities

Tags: python, appium, robotframework

when i write a simple test case i get an error like below

```
==============================================================================
Example                                                                       
==============================================================================
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No application is open
Example Case                                                          | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: platform name is missing in the capabilities
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Example                                                               | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

My robot file

```
*** Settings ***
Library    AppiumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${REMOTE_URL}  secretHubLink
${APP}    secretAppUrl
${PLATFORM_NAME}    Android
${PLATFORM_VERSION}    10
${DEVICE_NAME}    Galaxy S20

*** Test Cases ***
Example Case
    Open Application  ${REMOTE_URL}  platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}  platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}  deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}    app=${APP}   name=Robot Framework Sample Test    build=Appium Python Robot
```

My requirements.txt
robotframework-appiumlibrary

My Packages: (pip freeze)

```
Appium-Python-Client==2.7.1
async-generator==1.10
attrs==22.2.0
certifi==2022.12.7
decorator==5.1.1
docutils==0.19
exceptiongroup==1.1.0
h11==0.14.0
idna==3.4
kitchen==1.2.6
outcome==1.2.0
PySocks==1.7.1
robotframework==6.0.1
robotframework-appiumlibrary==2.0.0
selenium==4.7.2
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
trio==0.22.0
trio-websocket==0.9.2
urllib3==1.26.13
wsproto==1.2.0
selenium==4.7.2
```

- Os: Linux / Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- Python version: 3.8.10

Answer (score 0):

```
${REMOTE_URL}               http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
${MAIN_ACTIVITY}            com.dev

*** Keywords ***
Start Up Application
    [Documentation]    Starts up application session
    [Arguments]    ${platformName}    ${platformVersion}=    ${deviceName}=    ${portNumber}=4723
    ${appName}=              Get App Name
    ${bundleName}=     Run Keyword If    '${platformName.lower()}' == 'ios'     Get iOS Bundle Name
    ...                ELSE                                                     Get Android Bundle Name
    Run Keyword If    '${platformName.lower()}' == 'ios'    Open Application     ${REMOTE_URL}    waitForQuiescence=false    wdaEventloopIdleDelay=3     platformName=${platformName}    platformVersion=${platformVersion}    deviceName=${deviceName}    app=${appName}    bundleId=${bundleName}      autoAcceptAlerts=true    connectHardwareKeyboard=true
    ...    ELSE    Open Application    ${REMOTE_URL}    platformName=${platformName}   platformVersion=${platformVersion}    deviceName=${deviceName}    appPackage=${bundleName}    appActivity=${MAIN_ACTIVITY}     autoGrantPermissions=true     noReset=true
```

Comment: Thanks dmytro but it didnt work.

Comment: hm, works properly for me

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Smoke Demo
...
#Test Setup    AppiumLibrary.Launch Application
Test Teardown    Close Application
Library    AppiumLibrary
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${ANDROID_AUTOMATION_NAME}    UIAutomator2
${ANDROID_APP}                AbsPath to Your .apk
${ANDROID_PLATFORM_NAME}      Android
${ANDROID_PLATFORM_VERSION}   %{ANDROID_PLATFORM_VERSION=13}

*** Test Cases ***
Should Open App
  Open Test Application

*** Keywords ***
Open Test Application
  Open Application  http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub  automationName=${ANDROID_AUTOMATION_NAME}
  ...  platformName=${ANDROID_PLATFORM_NAME}  platformVersion=${ANDROID_PLATFORM_VERSION}
  ...  app=${ANDROID_APP}  appPackage=io.appium.android.apis  appActivity=.app.SearchInvoke
```

Please check this one a simpler option, works for me

[here](https://github.com/appium-boneyard/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/apps/ApiDemos/bin/ApiDemos-debug.apk) sample .apk that I use for this test

 Guide with simple example [here](https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary)

 [source code](https://github.com/DimaBerezovskyi/appium-robot-framework)